# clearInterval inside of a function is not clearing ,when the function is called and react state changed after executing other functions

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
const [state, setstate] = useState([])

const changestate = () =>{
        setstate([])
}


var Interval

function start(){   
    Interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("repeat this")
    }, 3000)  
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(Interval)
}


<button onClick={()=>changestate()}>change state</button>
<button onClick={()=>start()}>start</button>
<button onClick={()=>stop()}>stop</button>
```

If I click start button 1st to start interval and then stop button it clears the interval fine. but if I click change state in the middle and want to stop, the interval doesn't clear. I think its because of the re-declaration of var interval. but i am not finding other ways to achieve the same. any idea? I just want this interval to start and stop anytime I want without any intervention.

Comment: You have to clear on `start`, otherwise you will initiate two intervals but would only have a handle on the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `Interval` variable is recreated (with the value `undefined`) every time your component function is called again.

Typically you start timers and such in a `useEffect` callback, and stop them in its cleanup callback, controlling the process with a state variable. Here's an example, see comments:

```
function Example() {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    // State tells you whether the timer is running
    const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);

    // Start the imter or stop it based on state changes
    useEffect(() => {
        let handle = 0;
        if (running) {
            handle = setInterval(() => {
                console.log("repeat this")
            }, 3000);
        }
        // Return a cleanup function that clears the interval
        return () => clearInterval(handle);
    }, [running]); // <== Dependency says to re-call the callback when `running` changes

    const changeState = () =>{
        setState([]);
    };

    const start = () => {
        setRunning(true);
    };

    const stop = () => {
        setRunning(false);
    };

    return <>
        <button onClick={changeState}>change state</button>
        <button onClick={start} disabled={running}>start</button>
        <button onClick={stop}  disabled={!running}>stop</button>
    </>;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Example() {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    // State tells you whether the timer is running
    const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);

    // Start the imter or stop it based on state changes
    useEffect(() => {
        let handle = 0;
        if (running) {
            handle = setInterval(() => {
                console.log("repeat this")
            }, 3000);
        }
        // Return a cleanup function that clears the interval
        return () => clearInterval(handle);
    }, [running]); // <== Dependency says to re-call the callback when `running` changes

    const changeState = () =>{
        setState([]);
    };

    const start = () => {
        setRunning(true);
    };

    const stop = () => {
        setRunning(false);
    };

    // Sadly, can't use <> ... </> in Stack Snippets
    return <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={changeState}>change state</button>
        <button onClick={start} disabled={running}>start</button>
        <button onClick={stop}  disabled={!running}>stop</button>
    </React.Fragment>;
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

That said, you can also keep [information like this in a `ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables), but you need to be sure to clear the timer when the component unmounts (which will require a `useEffect` anyway). There are use cases both ways. For instance, in the example above I've used the state information to know which buttons to enable/disable. Both that and the code in the `useEffect` callback ensure that you won't start a timer twice (as [VLAZ pointed out the current code might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721584/clearinterval-inside-of-a-function-is-not-clearing-when-the-function-is-called/66721652?noredirect=1#comment117943863_66721584)). Also, the `useEffect` cleanup hook means that the timer is automatically stopped when the component is unmounted.

Answer (score 3):

Every time your component is updated a new `interval` reference is created. You need to store the interval reference in `useRef`.

I don't recommend you to store the interval function in the component `state` if you want to avoid unnecessary state updates:

```
const [state, setstate] = useState([]);
const interval = useRef(null);

function start(){   
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("repeat this");
    }, 3000)  
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(interval.current);
}
```

**Note:** Remember to stop the timer when component is unmounted:

```
useEffect(()=> stop(), []);
```

Comment: I like this solution because you don't need to update the state every time the button is pressed and will not cause unnecessary re-renders

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
.....
  const [startTimer, setStartTimer] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (startTimer) {
      const Interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("repeat this");
      }, 3000);
      return () => clearInterval(Interval);
    }
  }, [startTimer]);

  function start() {
    setStartTimer(true);
  }
  function stop() {
    setStartTimer(false);
  }
....
      <button onClick={() => start()}>start</button>
      <button onClick={() => stop()}>stop</button>
....
```

Comment: This is very similar to @T.J. Crowder answer

Comment: Yes i realized that, i recommend you to use the one with useRef hook, thank you for your questions ive learned something today.